# jquery jsTree with multiple cascade select checkbox

Tags: jquery, jstree

I am trying to design a user permission settings screen with jquery jstree plugin like bellow image .

[image]

I not found any example in jstree with multiple checkbox.

Please help me how to do this with jstree,or suggest me any plugin or approach to  complete this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <link href="jstree/themes/default/style.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-treetable/3.2.0/jquery.treetable.js"></script>
    <script src="jstree/jstree.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstreegrid/3.9.5/jstreegrid.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(() => {      

              // load jstree
            $("#jstree").jstree({
                plugins: ["grid",  "sort","checkbox"],
                core: {
                    data: [
                        { "id": "ajson1", "parent": "#", "text": "Simple root node" },
                        { "id": "ajson2", "parent": "#", "text": "Root node 2" },
                        {
                            "id": "ajson3", "parent": "ajson2", "text": "Child 1", "data": {
                                "totalAmount": "5060",
                                "itemcode": "38"
                            },
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "ajson4", "parent": "ajson2", "text": "Child 2", "data": {
                                "totalAmount": "5060",
                                "itemcode": "38"
                            },
                        },

                    ]
                },
                // configure tree table
                grid: {
                    columns: [
                        { width: 'auto', header: "Outlet" },

                        { width: 'auto', value: "totalAmount", header: "NoOfBills", cellClass: "aright" },

                        { width: 'auto', value: "itemcode", header: "Amount", cellClass: "aright" }

                    ],
                    resizable: true,



                }
            });
        });

    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="jstree">zdsd</div>
</body>

</html>
```

[image]

The code produced above design but I want to make it like my referenced image.

Comment: Please share your code, explicity the markup, so we get an [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @UfguFugullu please check I add the code